# Multi-tenant Django applications using Mongoengine

Tags: django, request, multi-tenant, mongoengine

I want to build a multi tenant architecture for a SAAS system. We are using Django as our backend and mongoengine as our main database and gunicorn as our web-server.

Our clients are a few big companies, so the number of databases pre-allocating space shouldn't be a problem.

The first approach we took was to write a middleware to determine the source of the request to properly connect to a mongoengine database. Here is the code:

```
class MongoConnectionMiddleware(object):
  def process_request(self, request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
      mongo_connect(request.user.profile.establishment)
```

And the mongo_connect method:

```
def mongo_connect(establishment):
  db_name = 'db_client_%d' % establishment.id
  connect(db_name)
```

This will register the "default" alias as the db_name for every mongoengine request.

But it seems that when many concurrent users from different companies are making requests, each one sets the default db_name to it's own name.

As an example:
Company A makes a request and connects to database A. While A is making it's work company B connects to database B. This makes A also connect to B's database in the process, so A fails to find some ids.

¿Is there a way to isolate the connection to the mongo database per request to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately MongoEngine seems to be designed around a very basic use case of a single primary connection and multiple auxiliary connections.
http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/guide/connecting.html#connecting-to-mongodb

To get around the default connection logic, I define the first connection I come across as the default, I also add it as a named connection. I then add any subsequent connection as named connections only.
https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/607#issuecomment-38651532

You can use the `with_db` decorator to switch from one connection to another, but it's a contextmanager call, which means as soon as you leave the `with` statement, it will revert. It also still requires a default connection.
http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/guide/connecting.html#switch-database-context-manager

You might be able to put it inside a function and then yield inside the with to prevent it reverting immediately, I'm not sure if this is valid.

You could use a wrapper of some kind, either a function, class or a custom QuerySet, that checks the current django/flask session and switches the db to the appropriate connection.
I'm not sure if a QuerySet can do this, but it would probably be the nicest way if it can.
http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/guide/querying.html#custom-querysets

I included some code in this issue here where I change the database connection for my models.
https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/605

```
def switch(model, db):
    model._meta['db_alias'] = db
    # must set _collection to none so it is re-evaluated
    model._collection = None
    return model
MyDocument = switch(MyDocument, 'db-alias')
```

You'll also want to take a look at the code that mongoengine uses to switch dbs.
Beware that mongo engine likes to cache things, so changing a few variables here and there doesn't always cause an effect. It's full of surprises like this.

**Edit:**
I should also add, that the 'connect' call won't pick up value changes. So calling connect with new parameters wont take effect unless its a new alias. Even the disconnect function (which isn't exposed publically) doesn't let you do this as the models will cache the connection. I mention this in some of the issues linked above and also here: https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/566

Comment: Is this fixed by mongoengine now?